# How to put an inline assembly jump to another function inside an IF condition?

Tags: c, assembly, arm, variadic-functions, inline-assembly

I'm trying to jump to a `fun2` function in assembly, because in C I haven't found a way to pass all variadic parameters to `fun2` via `fun1` without using a define like `#define fun1 (...) fun2 (__ VA_ARGS__)`

The problem is that if I move the jump instruction inside an IF condition, the code doesn't work, I'm working on an ARMv7 with a GCC compiler.

```
void fun2(char *format, ...){
   va_list arg_list;
   va_start(arg_list, format);
   vprintf(format, arg_list);
   va_end(arg_list);
}

//Works
void fun1(char *format, ...){
   __asm__("ldr pc,=fun2");
}

bool my_condition;
//Doesn't work
void fun1(char *format, ...){
   if(my_condition) {
      __asm__("ldr pc,=fun2");
   }
}

int main(){
   fun1("test: %d", 100);
}
```

Comment: This kind of code will not work and cannot be made to work.  Instead, build a variant of `fun2` that takes an argument of type `va_list` like `vprintf` does.

Comment: Declaring `my_condition`, then using it without first setting it to a known state will be a problem

Comment: @ryyker it is just an example, in any case I changed the example and initialized the ```my_condition``` variable

Comment: Once you post your question, and have comments and/or answers it is not a good idea to start making changes to the parts of your code _in your post_ people are commenting on.  Its fine to change your working code, not the posted code, except for formatting.  I've rolled it back.

Comment: @fuz I cannot change the header neither of ```fun1``` nor of ```fun2```. I am trying to integrate a new C library (which calls ```fun1``` to print its internal logs), in an already working project which uses ```fun2``` to print the logs on an UART port.

Comment: @ParminderSingh You may be able to cheat by implementing `fun1` completely in assembly.  But with inline assembly, you'll not be able to make it work.  So you cannot ask the project to make another function like `fun2` but taking a  `va_list`?

Comment: @fuz I can't understand why I can't put assembly code inside an IF statement

Comment: @ParminderSingh The compiler will have emitted unknown other code before the if statement, including code that changes the stack.  You cannot simply jump to another function from within C code.  That is not supported.

Comment: Does your compiler understand an attribute "naked" or similar? Anyway, you urgently need to look into the generated assembly code to see what the compiler generates from the conditional. Your best bet is already suggested: Use an all-assembly function.

Comment: And then there are binary tools (GCC: binutils) that can rename symbols during linking. Have you considered this? -- To get an answer at all, please [edit] your question and add a [mre] and details (product and version) of your compiler system. Currently we cannot help you really.

Comment: You could write `fun1` entirely in asm (in a separate `.s`, or as @thebusybee says with GNU C `__attribute__((naked))`, which GCC has supported for a long time for ARM), doing the load and conditional branch yourself.   Ideally you could get the linker to put it right before `fun2`, so you just need a load, test, and conditional `bxne lr`, with fall-through into `fun2` if it's not taken.  (Or `cbnz` forward to `fun2`, else fall into a `bx lr`)

Comment: Instead of this assembly hack, you could use a macro to test the condition before calling the logging function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to write an assembly solution, which seems to work (I see the log on the UART port), but I  noticed that this code only works if I use the R2 register, if I use any other register like R3, this code doesn't work anymore I wonder if this solution works just for luck

----Code modified according to suggestions---

file1.c

```
__attribute__((section(".text.fun"))) void fun2(char *format, ...) {
   va_list arg_list;
   va_start(arg_list, format);
   vprintf(format, arg_list);
   va_end(arg_list);
   
   /*...*/
}
```

file2.c

```
uint8_t *enable_trace = &(config.enable_trace);
__attribute__((naked, section(".text.fun"))) void fun1(char *format, ...) {
    __asm__(
        "ldr R12, =enable_trace    \n\
        ldr R12, [R12]             \n\
        ldrb R12, [R12]            \n\
        cmp R12, #1                \n\
        beq fun2                   \n\
        bx lr");
}

int main(){
   fun1("test: %d", 100);
}
```

Compiler: Snapdragon LLVM ARM Compiler 4.0.3 (based on llvm.org 4.0+)

ARM Cortex A7

Comment: You're effectively writing the whole function body in asm, so the calling convention is up to you.  `r0` is the first arg, `r1` is the second, `r2` is the third, `r3` is the fourth, and the rest are on the stack.  And the compiler is expecting execution to come out the bottom of the `asm()` statement with no registers or memory modified, because it's a Basic Asm statement (no operands or clobbers).  So that's totally broken.

Comment: You should be using `__attribute__((naked))` to tell the compiler to keep its hands off this function, not making a prologue/epilogue, and that you're taking responsibility for the whole function.  (So `bx lr` instead of `b end`.  Also, you can just `b fun2` because it should be very nearby.  You don't need to load its address from memory!)  Use a temp register that's call-clobbered but not one of the arg-passing registers, like `ip` (which stands for Intraprocess scratch, exactly what you need it for.)

Comment: @PeterCordes I did some research regarding these temp registers, from what I understand it should be the R12 register, could you confirm me please? I found this document (page 208), but I'm not sure if this is the correct documentation, In any case, register R12 seems to work. https://www.macs.hw.ac.uk/~hwloidl/Courses/F28HS/Docu/DEN0013D_cortex_a_series_PG.pdf

Comment: Yes, `ip` is an alias for `r12`, just like `lr` is an alias for `r14`.  https://azeria-labs.com/arm-data-types-and-registers-part-2/. So yes, `r12` is the register you want for this function: a call-clobbered register that's not used for arg passing.  (https://kolegite.com/EE_library/books_and_lectures/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B5/Assembly/ARM_calling_convention.pdf)

Comment: I rewrote the ```fun1``` according to the suggestions you gave me, I would like to publish it here, to have your opinion, but I don't know if I need to add a new answer or modify the answer I wrote above

Comment: You should fix this unsafe/broken answer so people (including me) can reverse their downvotes.  Deleting this and posting a new answer would still have those downvotes counting against your reputation (and possible question rate-limits if too many of your posts get too many downvotes.)

Comment: You could `beq fun2` if it's in range.  I think `b` has more range than `beq`, but if the compiler keeps them near each other then even a `beq` should still be in range to reach it directly.  You also don't need `.global enable_trace` to export that symbol in the symbol table so it's visible for other files to link with.  The compiler will already use that directive because you made it global, not `static`.

Comment: @PeterCordes I modified the code according to these two suggestions, it still works, and it's cleaner, ```fun2``` is declared in another c file, but I noticed that ```beq fun2``` still manages to jump to ```fun2```

Comment: Oh, in your question they were adjacent in one code block.  In separate files the linker might put them too far apart if the object files get put in a different order on the command line.  You could avoid that problem by using `__attribute__((section(".text.fun")))` or something on both to group them together, but unless / until it becomes a problem don't worry about it.

Comment: @PeterCordes You mean I should write something like this: ```__attribute__((naked)) __attribute__((section(".text.fun"))) void fun1(const char * format, ...)``` and ```__attribute__((section(".text.fun"))) void fun2(char *format, ...)``` may I ask if ".text.fun" has a particular meaning?

Comment: Yup, I *think* that would fix the problem if you ever  started getting linker errors.  I think those section names should work with most systems, but if you have a custom linker script it might actually cause a problem if it doesn't handle `.text.*`.  You can combine multiple attributes into `__attribute__((naked, section(".text.fun")))`.  But yeah, the `section` attribute just gets GCC to use `.section "whatever"` in the asm when compiling that file.

Comment: @PeterCordes thank you so much I edited the answer above again, I think I can mark it as a solution

Comment: The other thing I'd try to improve is one fewer levels of indirection.  Like have the asm load `config.enable_trace` directly, but that might need you to get a value from `offsetof` into the asm template string.  (And Extended Asm for a constraint like `"i"(offsetof(T, enable_trace))` isn't officially supported in naked functions unfortunately: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/ARM-Function-Attributes.html#ARM-Function-Attributes.)